# How to use custom component as library android

Tags: android, android-library, custom-component

I am working on app, where I have specific requirement to perform some actions on the list. I made specific custom list according to my need and this is working just fine.

Now my app structure is of such type that I have same Lists. So I have to manage same list style through out the project. I have some common function to perform in almost each Activities due to same type of requirement.

Now as I have created whole Adapter of List and List items, now to save time I just want to create the Library type thing.but I have no idea how to do it. Following are things that I want to achieve from this library .

- I want to set only data source to the Library that will contain the ListView, Item views and Custom adapter
- I want the callback that will notify current activity about the operation that is being performed.

> So even though I know How to make callbacks/interface and other
>   things, I just want to know How can I make Library that will consist
>   on my own made Listview and its Adapter that will only supply callback
>   of it actions to the activity.

**Note:** I know I can Implement it in Fragment and use fragment where needed, but for clean architecture can I made library if yes then How?

Please help me and tell me how can I do it?

Comment: do you have to use this list in different activities but same application?

Comment: yes, I need to use same list and same its functionality in different activities and fragments

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You have made a custom list that is shared in the entire project and you want to receive callbacks from the list but only in the current Activity ?

Comment: @PankajSati I have made an Activity and created a ListView in it, and custom adapter that is performing many  things on the Data source. Now I just wan to move this ListView and Adapter as a library and than want to receive only call backs in anyplace where I want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to menu and choose new module, select android library

Move your adapter and layout to that module, dont forget other assets, classes and interfaces as well (anything you need). You can copy paste to minimize the breaking changes and then delete after you have added the library.

If your adapter or anything need any dependencie you have to added on the library gradle

Now go to your app graddle and add the module there

```
implementation project(':yourLibraryName')
```

Comment: then when I want to use that ListView inside my Layout How would I do that

Comment: Just add the view on your layout and set the adapter, the library is the adapter you can add the view anywhere you want

Comment: ok,so you are saying to create a library that only has the Adapter and the relevant layouts of Item designs, etc, and then in my app just take the Recycler-view and set that adapter to that ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you break separation of concern. If you need an abstract Activity to replicate the logic of setting the adapter then you create that base activity in the app module using the library module. This way if thar base activity need to be expanded with more functionalities you will change the app module code, because those other functionalities have no concern with the library module.

Answer (score 1):

As you need to use in same application there is no need to create library.

1. For layout you can create a separate layout for your listview which
   you can just include in your Activity and Fragment layouts.
2. For Adapter you can create an interface either inside your Adapter class, or as separate file and add that interface instance to your Adapter class constructor.
3. Implement same interface in all activity/fragment which will be using this list and adapter and pass that local instance of interface to Adapter constructor while initializing.

On any event in listview call interface method and control will be passed to called class or fragment.

Comment: can you give me example of that ? or can you elaborate more

Comment: It is difficult to give example as it is almost full fledged app you are asking for. You can ask question if you did not get any particular part of solution proposed.